# How to transfer bold text over /posts endpoint

Tags: linkedin-api

I've coded successfully for a client a call to the /posts endpoint that allow for the publishing of a post with text content, and a media if available. However i get problems when trying to publish bold expressions.

My client wishes to transfer text bold to the API, for that purposes he marks up the bold text with html :

`Hello <b> World </b>`

I tried to replace the   tags with *{content}* which is replaced by bold text in the linkedin client editor, however when transfered over the API in the commentary field of /posts ; this doesn't work.

I see here that the type of commentary field is little text : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/little-text-format?view=li-lms-2023-10

I don't see any information regarding rich text formating here (bold, italic, &c...)

Is there a way to maintain the format of the text to preserve bold, italic or other such rich text format over the /posts API ?